# How to differentiate between actionresults

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My page load action result and http post action result both pass in the model.

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult StepTwo(PostcodesModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult StepTwo(PostcodesModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Since they both take in the model, what can I add to make them unique ?

Comment: Are you by any chance the same StevieB? http://www.mixcloud.com/stephanbreuer32/

Comment: Nope sorry, he looks much cooler

Comment: Haha :-D That would be a big coincidence :-). Have a good day!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [**ActionName**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute, it represents an attribute that is used for the name of an action. If it is not present the name of the method is used.

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult StepTwo(PostcodesModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ActionName("StepTwo")]
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult StepTwoPost(PostcodesModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't know about this attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult StepTwo(PostcodesModel model)
{
    return View();
}

[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult StepTwo(PostcodesModel model, FormCollection additionalData)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: @MichalB. I left a comment on his answer.